How to rename public directory in Larvael Herd?
I'm using Laravel Herd for my local development. I need to rename the public folder on my hosting to public_html so it can load my application. After renaming public folder and adding necessary changes in AppServiceProvider.php and vite.config.js, Herd says "404 Site Not Found" error. Is there a way to configure herd to load application from public_html folder instead of public folder?
I didn't found any relating discussion about this problem on herd. php artisan serve still works, But I need herd to work with public_html folder too.

maybe create a symlink between the two?

I had the same issue with herd. take a look at the Custom Drivers section on there docs. just rename the web to 'public_html' and it works like magic.
you will need to create a folder Drivers and then create a php file with the name 'CustomLaravelValetDriver' and then paste the code in there that is in the custom driver section.
